# How to arrange buttons in a row?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have defined separate functions, and have a `main()` function. 
In the `main()` function, I have several buttons, which call to other functions when clicked. 
eg.

```
def main():
    global root
    global tkinter
    global canvas
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Shapes Quiz - Flow Computing")
    Button(root, text ="1", bg="Grey", width=10, command=pentagon).pack()
    Button(root, text ="2", bg="Grey", width=10, command=circle).pack()
    Button(root, text ="3", bg="Grey", width=10, command=diamond).pack()
    Button(root, text ="4", bg="Grey", width=10, command=hexagon).pack()
    Button(root, text ="5", bg="Grey", width=10, command=triangle).pack()
    Button(root, text ="6", bg="Grey", width=10, command=square).pack()
    Button(root, text ="7", bg="Grey", width=10, command=rectangle).pack()
    Button(root, text ="8", bg="Grey", width=10, command=heptagon).pack()
    Button(root, text ="9", bg="Grey", width=10, command=octagon).pack()
    Button(root, text ="10", bg="Grey", width=10, command=oval).pack()
    Button(root, text ="Help", bg="Grey", width=10, command=help).pack()
    Button(root, text ="Clear", bg="Red", width=10, command=clearshapes).pack()
    Button(root, text ="QUIT", bg="Red", width=10, command=quit).pack()
```

I'm sure there must be an easier way to organize these buttons. I have heard of the use of frames and grids, and even co-ordinates; but I am still unsure of how to do this.

I would like to organize the buttons so they are *horizontal*, not *vertical* as they are appearing currently.

Comment: A couple of other links: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Correct, but that tutorial does not provide the answer i'm looking for, it doesn't say how to arrange multiple buttons.

Comment: codeape's link does provide a bit more info. Will have a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `pack()` to [`pack(side='left')`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack-method).

Comment: This answer works, however it kinda squishes the canvas to the right, is there any way to put the text at the bottom BELOW the canvas, in this formation?

Comment: I have realised, that using
    BOTTOM
means that all buttons appear at the bottom, but they jump back to vertical when this is applied?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, there is an easier way to do this with the grid geometry manager (the link is already in the comments):

```
# ...
root.title("Shapes Quiz - Flow Computing")
BUTTONS = [{"text":"1", "bg":"Grey", "width":10, "command":pentagon},
           {"text":"2", "bg":"Grey", "width":10, "command":circle},
           # Rest of the buttons
           {"text":"QUIT", "bg":"Red", "width":10, "command":quit}]
for i, options in enumerate(BUTTONS):
    Button(root, **options).grid(row=0, column=i)
```

Note that you always use almost the same code, so it may look cleaner if you use a for loop and declare the options of the widgets in advance.